# What is the max number of users you can have access a music file stored on a localhost?

Tags: android, apache, tomcat, localhost, android-mediaplayer

I am creating an android application that will access media files (.mp3) stored on a local host using a URL. Since the app is intended to be used by multiple people simultaneously (100+ people accessing the files at the same time) accessing the same media file. How do I make sure that this functionality works? Since currently while testing I am the only person accessing the file which is not creating any issues. I need to make sure it works fine with multiple users.

The Android application I am building is intended to work only when connected to a particular wifi network (which will be provided by the client). So what I tried was to create an FTP server using XAMPP and store the music file in the intended folder which now can be accessed using a URL. Now, since I am the only one accessing this file on my application, I haven't run into any issues, but my concern is when multiple people access this file with the same URL from a single localhost, will it cause any issues?

Comment: You should tell about your server. Your app is irrelevant.

Comment: You're basically asking how to do load testing,  which is too broad a question for stackoverflow's focus ([help/on-topic]) also note: "I'd like to receive insight" is not a proper question ([ask])

Comment: (Also: localhost scales well, as there's typically one user per server. Likely you're referring to something else)

Comment: @OlafKock - Thank you for sharing the articles, they were helpful. I am a novice at localhost or hosting files in general, actually, I don't even know many of the terms used in the server client / networking domain. I have edited the question to make it more understandable using the info from the articles.